# Firebase task is returned before data is written to database

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

To write to my database, I send my data to a firebase function. When the data is written (in my mind, that would be when the task is completed...) the next activity should load and be able to download the written data. Perhaps there are more effective ways to do this, but that is besides the point.

My firebase function is as follows, and does what it should, except for returning the task to early I suppose.

Note: It is only the first "set function" that needs to be written to the database before the task is returned.

```
exports.createPostHandler = (data, context) => {
//Post
admin.database().ref('/posts/' + data.team + '/' + data.UID).set({
    UID : data.UID,
    sender : data.username,
    user : context.auth.uid,
    title : data.title,
    time : data.time,
    imagelink : data.imagelink,
    text : data.text
}).then(() => {
    console.log('User ' + context.auth.uid + ' created post ' + data.UID);

    //Postcompressed
    admin.database().ref('/team/' + data.team + '/posts/' + data.UID).set({
    UID : data.UID,
    sender : data.username,
    user : context.auth.uid,
    title : data.title,
    time : data.time
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('Created compressedpost ' + data.UID + ' in team ' + data.team);
    });
});
```

On the client side, the code is as follows, and does what it should, except for loading loading the next page before data has been written to the database. The "PostPage" activity works if I access it a couple of seconds after the data has been written, so I am sure that this is the issue.

```
FirebaseFunctions.getInstance().getHttpsCallable("createPost").call(createDatamap(UID, title, posttext, username, time, ""))
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<HttpsCallableResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                            PostCompressed postCompressed = new PostCompressed(UID, title, username, time, null, null);
                            postDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Du har skapat ett inlägg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startPostPage(postCompressed);
                        } else {
                            v.setClickable(true);
                            alertView.findViewById(R.id.loadview).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Du kunde inte skapa ett inlägg... Något gick snett!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

The question I have is 'Why does the function return it's task before the data has been written? Shouldn't the task be "finished" when the data is written?'

Answer (score 2):

Since the `set()` operations are asynchronous (see [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#set)), you have to return the promises they returned in your promise chain, as follows, in order to have "Cloud Functions knowing when to respond to the client, after all the work is complete" (Excerpt from this SO answer: [CRUD data in firestore using firebase function onCall. What happens to any async operation (Promise) within it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51814520/crud-data-in-firestore-using-firebase-function-oncall-what-happens-to-any-async)).

```
exports.createPostHandler = (data, context) => {
//Post
return admin.database().ref('/posts/' + data.team + '/' + data.UID).set({
    UID : data.UID,
    sender : data.username,
    user : context.auth.uid,
    title : data.title,
    time : data.time,
    imagelink : data.imagelink,
    text : data.text
}).then(() => {
    console.log('User ' + context.auth.uid + ' created post ' + data.UID);

    //Postcompressed
    return admin.database().ref('/team/' + data.team + '/posts/' + data.UID).set({
    UID : data.UID,
    sender : data.username,
    user : context.auth.uid,
    title : data.title,
    time : data.time
 }).then(() => {
        console.log('Created compressedpost ' + data.UID + ' in team ' + data.team);
        return true;
 });
});
```

Comment: Work perfectly! Thank you. I suppose I now know how promises work a bit better... ;)